# Change border-bottom of mat autocomplete

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have this [stackblitx example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-autocomplete-with-selected-value-ssdcdk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.scss)

I have applied styling as

```
autocomplete-display-example {
  .mat-form-field.mat-focused {
    .mat-form-field-ripple {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  }
  .mat-form-field-infix {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
    // background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

I want to remove the black line and have a dotted green line. In the demo, the black line is still visible. How to remove that? I tried [as said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127099/changing-angular-mat-input-border-bottom-color) but it seems that the style wont work.

Or better if I can remove it altogether so that I just have green dots

Update:

Once I click on the text box, the green dotted line should be replaced with yellow line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by overriding the style:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
    height: 1px !important;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

[A complete stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-autocomplete-with-selected-value-smhssz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.scss)

**UPDATE:**

When input is focused, then it is possible to apply the following styles:

```
.mat-form-field.mat-focused {
    .mat-form-field-infix {
      border-bottom: 0px;
    // background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

[A stackblitz example with focused `.mat-form-field` can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-autocomplete-with-selected-value-smhssz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.scss)

Comment: Thanks you but the `yellow` color is not visible anymore when I focus on the input box :(

Comment: One more issue, which I think will happen is the error color `red` which is added by form validation :(

Comment: @User985614 please, see my updated answer and stackblitz example

Comment: Sincere apologies, for coming back but , the behaviour should be to `hide` green and have just `yellow` line when `active`. I'll be clear and update the question. Many Thanks

Comment: Hello @StepUp, let me know if I need to add more details

Comment: @User985614 please, see my updated answer

Comment: Absolutely. I was away for few days, I'll test it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will use this way to fix it, I am using Angular  "@angular/material": "^10.2.1".

```
  // Overwrite border bottom color or underline to input with chip component. 
  // Overwrite normal appearance and focused event.
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline,
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple{
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

Before (Include the border bottom)

[image]

After
[image]